# How can we dismiss all displayed notification in electron js?

Tags: notifications, electron, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using electron js and used Notification from electron. I want to close/dismiss all notification after reading from another place. How can I manage that?

electron version: 12.2.1

Please suggest me the proper method to dismiss/close all notification from panel.

Notification logic is in main process. Or else I can shift that logic in renderer process. Any how I want to dismiss all logic from notification panel.

Answer (score -1):

You could use:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/notification#notificationclose
And loop through all the notifications.

Pseudocode:
to send notification
send notification and add to array
to clear
for n in notificationarray
n.close()

Comment: We can close the notification from close method, but my question is that how can I get all delivered notification list so that I can find particular notification and close that one?